# Create Virtual Machine templates using Virtual PC

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vdi, windows-virtual-pc

Is there a way to create a **Virtual Machine Template** from which I can then create virtual machines?

What I would like to achieve is:

1. Create a virtual machine using Virtual PC
2. Install all programs that I need in that VM
3. Then make that VM as a template for all the VM's I create in the future.

Is this possible at all? If so, please share any pointers to it.

Comment: You didn't specify whether you need 64-bit VM templates.  VPC isn't going to work for that.

Comment: @JakeOshins I know that Virtual PC does not support 64 bit. I was meaning 32 bit VM templates in my question. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating a Template from a Virtual Hard Disk**

You can use sysprep to create templates from virtual machines created of virtualPC. When you create a template from a virtual hard disk. Sysprep strips the virtual machine of its computer identity. If you want to continue to use the source virtual machine, you must clone the virtual machine before you create the template."

Procedure

The following procedure tells how to create a virtual machine template from an existing virtual hard disk.  Prepare the source virtual hard disk, which has the operating system installed, for duplication:

- Run Sysprep on the .vhd file to remove computer identity information from the disk.
- Install Virtual Machine Additions on the .vhd file.
- Add the source .vhd file to the library.
- In Library view, in the Actions pane, click New Template.
- Complete the New Template Wizard.

Note:-  There may be some variations in steps, depending on the guest OS.